# How to make parts of a container/div to selectively ignore the click event in angular?

Tags: angular, click

consider the following code:

HTML:

```
    <div (click)="clicked()" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between">
        <div>Item 1</div>
        <div>Item 2</div>
        <div>Item 3</div>
    </div>
```

How do I make it so that the 'clicked()' function is not ran when I click item 3? But runs when I click anywhere else in the row?

Comment: Can't you assign click event on the individual items?

Comment: I can but I wanted the clicked() function to run when I click anywhere on the row(apart from on item 3) even outside the other items. @Fateme Fazli answer works as desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use stopPropagation:

```
<div (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">Item 3</div>
```